Dual Graphs of Configurations / Line Arrangements
In something I am working, I have stumbled upon the following combinatorial object, where given $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in general position, call $P=\{p_1,p_2,...,p_n\}$, create the $n\choose 2$ infinite lines given by all pairs of distinct points from $P$. This creates a line arrangement, which divides the plane into some amount of regions and we can create the dual graph (region graph, adjacency graph, tope graph(?) ) by taking the vertex list to be the regions, and connect them if they share an edge.
Yet since this the lines emerge from specific points, we do not have arbitrary lines, every $n-1$ line intersect at one point. Apparently this is a specific structured called a Configuration. There is a complete quadrangle example, but I could not find any reference to the generalized version of this idea, the $(n_{n-1}, {n\choose2}_2)$ configuration.
Essentially, I want some references to see the properties of the dual graphs given by such configurations and how the dual graph changes as we increase / decrease $n$ to think about some inductive arguments. There are some resources I found, but they mainly involve dual graphs of line arrangements and oriented matroids, those I found are below:

On tope graphs of complexes of oriented matroids, Knauer, K., Marc, T.
Hyperplane Arrangements with a Lattice of Regions, Björner, A. et al.
Regions of Hyperplane Arrangements

I am yet to look at these references in detail yet, and I would appreciate any other references or insights you can provide.
